# A better way to deal with scrolling inside iframes?

Tags: usability, scrolling

I have site A, a dashsboarding site, that we are embedding in site B. Site A is built as a single page application that cannot be auto height. It's intended to be 100vh height. I embed it in Site B, but I'm trying to avoid scrolling confusion. Right now I'm using sticky positioning to get the iframe to stick and act like a full-window application for the moments you are looking at it.

Is there a better way to handle this? Maybe a dedicated area on the right to scroll the overall page instead of iframe? Or js that always pulls the iframe to the top of the your screen so your never stuck with an iframe half in view?

[Here is the site in question.](https://www.savi.org/apps/dipin/nearwest.html)

Comment: Out of the question to render a static preview for embedding on site B, then [`.open()`ing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=net-5.0#system-int32-tostring(system-iformatprovider)) site A in a popout?

Comment: Not a bad idea... I'll give that some thought. That would definitely improve load time and usability for site B.

Comment: I must have had the wrong link copied when I posted that comment. Should be [`.open()`ing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: As the question currently stands it feels more like an implementation issue, can you pull out the part that is relevant to the user experience?